# Exclude directory from webpack copy in vue CLI

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli

I have a Vue3 project made with Vue CLI 5.0.1

My setup has a public folder where I have static assets that I need to serve, but it is very heavy (1GB of assets) so when I launch the `npm run serve` command I get the build stuck on `[92%] sealing (asset processing copy-webpack-plugin)`.

I need so to exclude the public/resources directory from the copy-webpack-plugin.

I tried with the following config added in my vue.config.js:

```
    chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.plugin("copy").tap(([options]) => {
      options[0].ignore.push("resources/**");
      return [options];
    });
 }
```

But I get this error:

`ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'ignore' of undefined`

Comment: I tested your approach and it worked in my case, no errors. Something else is going on. Could you share your `vue.config.js`?

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered [on Github](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/7047).

The options format has changed so you need to modify your code as follows:

```
chainWebpack: (config) => {
  config.plugin("copy").tap(([options]) => {
    options.patterns[0].globOptions.ignore.push("resources/**");
    return [options];
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all solutions found on Google, nothing worked for me to exclude files at build by modifying vue.config.js.

I ended up using rimraf to remove the files from the dist folder post-build:

npm install rimraf --save-dev

setup in package.json like this:

```
"scripts": {
 "build": "vue-cli-service build && npm run remove-files",
 "remove-files": "rimraf dist/somefile.js dist/anotherfile.css"
}
```